# How to export Selenium output to PHP?

Tags: php, selenium

It seems like Selenium IDE for Firefox has no default export to PHP.
I need Selenium in order to convert its output to PHP to be used in Drupal.

How can I install the PHP language export in order to achive this goal?

Comment: hi can you mark this answr as accepted thanks.... every liitle helps.. not to sound like a tesco ad or anything :)

Answer (score 2):

it's now an add on in mozilla called [selenium php formatters](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/selenium-ide-php-formatters/)

There is also a Chrome extension released in 2016. See downloads at http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/

Comment: This add-on is not even capable of creating syntactically correct PHP. And once you manually add the missing semicolons, you realize that the code tries to reassign `$this` to a new reference... Really, this extension shouldn't be advertised.

Comment: I haven't used it in quite a while, but I'm sure there are more up to date extensions available

Comment: @EdwardBlack this is the git page if you want to fork the code https://github.com/brokenthumbs/PHP-Formatter

Comment: @EdwardBlack If you could use Chrome, there's an extension that was released just last year. http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/  - there's lots listed on this page

Answer (score 0):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50089367/cant-see-file-edit-actions-menu-bar-on-firefox-selenium-ide), the export feature has disapeared from Selenium IDE, you could use an [alternative](https://a9t9.com/blog/selenium-ide-2018/) ([another comparison](https://alternativeto.net/software/selenium-ide/)).