# Can't see File/Edit/Actions menu bar on Firefox Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

[image: Screenshot]

Hi,
I'm just starting to learn Selenium & was trying to explore IDE for Firefox. 
I'm using Firefox 59.0.2 & Selenium IDE 3.0.2.

The IDE window, doesn't show me any menu bar options (File/Edit/..). I was looking forward to export the code in Java. How can I do that without the menu bar option itself?

Kindly refer to attached screen shot.
I would appreciate any help, I'm sure I'm missing something here, unless the options are entirely disabled in latest IDE version.

Comment: Helped with some formatting. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Right Click on the test case you created on IDE. Export option should be there